# Its 2017: How do you create tables with System.Data.SQLITE.EF6

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, system.data.sqlite

I've ready a number of old posts mentioning that System.Data.Sqlite allows you to talk to Entity Framework but not actually create the database tables.  It is 2017 now and I'm wondering if SQLite for Entity Framework 6 still lacks the ability to create a database using Code First.

FYI - I've used Entity Framework Core and I know that EFCore can create tables so I'd be surprised if EF6 can't, but I'm having a rough time trying to make it actually work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good question! All I know is [SQLite.CodeFirst](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.CodeFirst) package, although it seem to use non standard approach.

Answer (score 0):

"SQLite for EF6" is maintained here: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki and as far as I can see there are no plans to support Code First Migrations with that provider. DevArt has a commercial provider, that supports Code First with SQLite.